# Check given string in nested data structure using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Given string `'vivek'` to be search in below nested data structure & if string `'vivek'` present then I want outer `'id'` using ansible playbook:

```
{'results': [{'details': [{'id': '1', 'name': 'vivek'},
                          {'id': '2', 'name': 'ashwin'}],
              'id': '100'},
             {'details': [], 'id': '101'},
             {'details': [{'id': '1', 'name': 'vivek'},
                          {'id': '2', 'name': 'ashwin'}],
              'id': '102'}]}
```

Output required:

```
skipping: [localhost] => (item=['101'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['100') => {
    "msg": "100"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['102') => {
    "msg": "102"
}
```

I tried:

```
- name: List IDs which contains 'vivek'
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    results:
      - id: '100'
        details:
          - id: '1'
            name: 'vivek'
          - id: '2'
            name: 'ashwin'
      - id: '101'
        details:
          -
      - id: '102'
        details:
          - id: '1'
            name: 'vivek'
          - id: '2'
            name: 'ashwin'
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: results

    - set_fact:
        all_details: "{{ results | map(attribute='details') | list }}"

    - debug:
        var: all_details

#    - name: List of IDs, contains 'vivek'
#      debug:
#        msg: "{{ item.id }}"
#      loop: "{{ all_details }}"
#      when: 'vivek' in items.names
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter with `results` var from your playbook vars definition. `id` used in the playbook vars and your Output required are different.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ results | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "[?details[?name=='vivek']].id"
```

gives,

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "100",
        "103"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Its requires additional installation of 'jmespath'

Comment: [Install it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html). The name of the package would most likely be `py-jmespath` or `python-jmespath`

Comment: would be great if we can achieve this without additional packages

Comment: There probably are other ways to achieve the same result but for certain scenarios I find jmespath comparatively simpler to implement and readable.

Comment: On this one, indeed, `subelements` will work, but that is because the lists are fairly easy and not deeply nested, in most of the cases, indeed, `json_query` will win it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to achieve it with the addition of [`jmespath` and `json_query`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63231068/2123530), then you can achieve it with the [`subelements` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements).

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no  
  vars:
    results:
      - id: '100'
        details:
          - id: '1'
            name: 'vivek'
          - id: '2'
            name: 'ashwin'
      - id: '101'
        details:
          -
      - id: '102'
        details:
          - id: '1'
            name: 'vivek'
          - id: '2'
            name: 'ashwin'  
        
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.id }}"
      loop: "{{ results | subelements('details') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.1.name | default('None') }}"
      when: 
        - item.1.name is defined 
        - "'vivek' == item.1.name"
```

This gives the output:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=vivek) => {
    "msg": "100"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=ashwin) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=None) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=vivek) => {
    "msg": "102"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=ashwin) 

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```